# dynamics crm role sql

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Good day. Trying to create a view in MS SQL that retrieves user data MS Dynamics CRM. I just need to extract the name of the employee and to correlate it with the identifier of one particular group. But the problem is that I can not find a relation with the security roles. Please give an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table you are looking for is SystemUserRoles

```
select systemuser.firstname, systemuser.lastname, role.name, role.*
from systemuser
join SystemUserRoles on systemuser.systemuserid = systemuserroles.SystemUserId
join [role] on systemuserroles.roleid = [role].roleid
```